# Jupyter ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have the following project structure:

```
path_to_dir/
│
├── a_notebook.ipynb
└── testCases_v2.py
```

In the .py file I have defined several functions.

I'm trying to import them in the notebook like this:

```
from testCases_v2 import layer_sizes_test_case
```

However, I am getting:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'layer_sizes_test_case' from 'testCases_v2' (/path_to_dir/testCases_v2.py)

I even tried adding the directory to the system path:

```
import os
import sys
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('path_to_dir'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(module_path)
```

But the problem persists.

How to solve it? (And, yes, I checked that the name of the function I am importing is spelled correctly)

Comment: can you add a empy `__init__.py` file in that folder and try?

Comment: Hi @Nick, could you find a solution yet, Im running in a similar problem, would appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this:

```
path_to_dir/
│
├── a_notebook.ipynb
└── tests
       |
       └── testCases_v2.py
```

And in testCases_v2 you have a class with the same name.

1. You have to manually import the modules you want Jupyter take into
   account in sys.path In this case, the module is 'tests' and the path
   you have to include is 'path_to_dir'

   ```
     import sys  
     sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/dir')
   ```
2. In the module where your py files are, add an empty `__init__.py`

   ```
    path_to_dir/
    │
    ├── a_notebook.ipynb
    └── tests
        |
        ├──testCases_v2.py
        └── __init__.py
   ```

You should be able to import it now by doing:

```
from tests.testCases_v2 import testCases_v2
```

The [python doc about modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) might come in handy

Comment: it doesn't work